# Write a C++ pgm to read from a file "input.txt" , whenever a period is encountered insert newline and write modified content to "output.txt"

Tags: c++, file-io

Question: Write a program in C++ to read from a file "input.txt" and whenever a period is encountered in the file "input.txt" insert a newline character and then write the modified contents to a new file "output.txt" and save it. Finally print the number of periods encountered.

I wrote the following program however this program compiles fine but it doesn't execute so please help me out. Thanks and regards.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int count = 0;
    ofstream myFile;
    char ch;
    myFile.open("D:\\Files\\input.txt");
    myFile<<"Hi this is Yogish. I'm from Bengaluru, India. And you are ??"<<endl;
    myFile.close();

    ofstream myHandler;
    myHandler.open("D:\\Files\\output.txt");

    fstream handler;
    handler.open("D:\\Files\\input.txt");
    if(handler.is_open()){
                         while(!handler.eof()){
                                             handler>>ch;
                                             if(ch != '.'){
                                                   handler<<ch;
                                                   }
                                             else{
                                                  myHandler<<ch<<'\n';
                                                  handler<<'.'<<'\n';
                                                  count++;
                                                  }
                                                  }
                         }
    cout<<"The number of periods : "<<count++<<endl;
    system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific what you mean by "doesn't execute." Also, what did you discover when you tried to debug the program?

Comment: @RaymondChen what I meant by saying that it "doesn't execute" is when I compiled the program I din't get any errors but when I tried to execute it I just got a black screen and nothing else was happening so I just closed the console and I checked the output file but it was just blank. Once I modified code after seeing #AbhishekBansal answer my program is working fine.

Comment: What about the second question? What did you discover when you tried to debug the program? When you broke into the program, what line was it executing?

Comment: @RaymondChen Ya I tried debuuging it but the stepping wasn't working in DEV C++ on my machine (even tough I enabled debugging option )so I couldn't debug it so I just posted the question here looking for a solution.

Comment: You should figure out how to use your debugger. Then you can solve problems yourself instead of throwing yourself on the mercy of SO. it is 100x easier to debug a problem with a debugger than by just reading source code somebody handed to you without any comments or description of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the question means that you only have to write the modified contents to the new file output.txt. At present you are trying to write into input file as well.

You should read the entire line in one string and then use std::replace_if algorithm from the `<algorithm>` header.

Also, in general, you should avoid the check for termination condition as `file.eof()` since it is only set *after* the read operation. Hence, there is a possibility that the eof() bit is set after you read a character, which means that the last character read is invalid and you would output this invalid character to the file.

It will result in undefined behaviour.

Instead you should try something like:

```
bool isDot( const char& character ) {
  return character == '.';
}
```

And in your main function:

```
std::string newLine;

// enter the loop only if the read operation is successful
while ( getline( handler, newLine ) ) {
  count += std::count_if( newLine.begin(), newLine.end(), isDot );
  std::replace_if( newLine.begin(), newLine.end(), isDot, '\n' );
  myHandler << newLine;
}
```